# How to optimize firebase/firestore for a sensible synchronization tool for big online database?

Tags: sqlite, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, synchronization

In my app I have a lot of PNGs, about 150 mb. First time my user will download them all, but then the user should only download new/deleted/modified PNGs, not the ones that stay the same. How can I use Firebase/Firestore for this?

First, I decided to use SQLite as offline database, because I read that firebase will charge for offline reads. Then I read that when keepSync enabled and setPersistanceEnabled(true), Firebase will download my entire 150 mb database every time the app starts.
The problem is; my app is a mainly offline app. I don't to pay for offline usage, and I expect firebase to be smart and sync "on demand" and sync only "new stuff". To be clear, the user will only display my PNGs, not modify them. So data flow in my sample is one way; from online db to local device.

I hope I made it clear what I expect. Feel free to recommend other tools. I can change the order of my PNGs, add new PNGs, delete them, modify them, but in the end most will stay same and I don't want to be charged for PNGs that are same for years.
Sorry for long post, but I couldn't see any solid answer despite a lot of questions.

Comment: *"Firebase will download my entire 150 mb database every time the app starts"* - That's not necessarily true.  *"I expect firebase to be smart and sync "on demand" and sync only "new stuff""* - that's exactly the way it works when persistence is enabled, which is the default for Android and iOS.

Comment: By the way, keepSynced and setPersistenceEnabled are APIs for Realtime Database, not Cloud Firestore.  Are you sure you haven't mixed up the two different databases?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen    in the detach listener section doc says "When you are no longer interested in listening to your data, you must detach your listener so that your event callbacks stop getting called. This allows the client to stop using bandwidth to receive updates", doesn't it mean it always consume some bandwidth just to listen online db if any changes? Thanks for the second answer btw

Comment: If you are not listening to anything, there is no data transferred, other than the overhead of establishing the connection.